# Kivy nested BoxLayout stacks widgets on bottom left corner

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying do dynamically build a Kivy layout with a vertical BoxLayout containing a varying number of custom `MyRow` widgets that can change at runtime.
[image: layout example]
each row is an horizontal BoxLayout

I'm not using a GridLayout because `MyRow` layout is being developed and can change in the near future adding widgets etc. like this example
[image: layout example 2]

But with the code below I only get small widgets stacked on top of each other in the bottom left corner of the window.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class MyRow(Widget):
    a = StringProperty('a')
    b = StringProperty('b')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainScreen(Widget):

    rows = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']] #example data

    mainLayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=5)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_widget(self.mainLayout)

        for r in self.rows:
            row_widget = MyRow()

            row_widget.a = r[0]
            row_widget.b = r[1]

            self.mainLayout.add_widget(row_widget)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and this is the kv file:

```
<MyRow>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        spacing: 30
        Label:
            id: a_label
            text: root.a
        Label:
            id: b_label
            text: root.b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sketch it says `MyRow` is based on an horizontal BoxLayout. But it is not. It is build on `widget`

Simply changing

```
class MyRow(Widget):
```

to

```
class MyRow(BoxLayout):
```

will solve your problem.

[image]

---

To get spacing right or better I would update your code to the following

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.base import Builder



class MyRow(BoxLayout):
    a = StringProperty('a')
    b = StringProperty('b')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):

    rows = [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]*5 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        for r in self.rows:
            row_widget = MyRow()

            row_widget.a = r[0]
            row_widget.b = r[1]

            self.add_widget(row_widget)



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and your kv

```
<MyRow>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 30
    Label:
        id: a_label
        text: root.a
    Label:
        id: b_label
        text: root.b
```

which gives you [image]

---

To inherit from a Boxlayot in python use `class Row(BoxLayout):` in kv file use `<Row@BoxLayout>:`

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so consider accepting or if it just helped you, you may consider upvoting it.